Intel® Ultimate N Wi-Fi Link 5300 doesn't work
my wifi doesn't work on my lubuntu 20/22 installed on my old thinkpad x200s. I am going to post some attempts I made while browsing the online support pages but still it doesn't allow me even to do a wifi scan and doesn't show any existence of wifi connections on my manager. thank you, greetings.
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ rfkill unblock all
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE              SOFT    HARD
 0 wwan tpacpi_wwan_sw unblocked blocked
 1 wlan phy0           unblocked blocked
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ sudo rmmod iwlmvm && sudo modprobe iwlmvm
[sudo] password for blblbl: 
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlmvm is not currently loaded
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall network-manager
[sudo] password for blblbl: 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto   
I seguenti pacchetti sono stati installati automaticamente e non sono più richiesti:
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 linux-image-4.15.0-144-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-144-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-144-generic
Usare "sudo apt autoremove" per rimuoverli.
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 1 reinstallati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
È necessario scaricare 2.203 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 0 B di spazio su disco.
Scaricamento di:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 network-manager amd64 1.36.6-0ubuntu2 [2.203 kB]
Recuperati 2.203 kB in 1s (3.870 kB/s)    
(Lettura del database... 273895 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../network-manager_1.36.6-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb...
Estrazione di network-manager (1.36.6-0ubuntu2) su (1.36.6-0ubuntu2)...
Configurazione di network-manager (1.36.6-0ubuntu2)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per man-db (2.10.2-1)...
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ nmcli
enp0s25: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel 82567LM"
        ethernet (e1000e), 00:1F:16:36:23:87, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.134/24
        route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100
        route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::21f:16ff:fe36:2387/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

wls1: unavailable
        "Intel Ultimate N 5300"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 00:21:6A:94:0A:7C, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.1.1
        domains: homenet.telecomitalia.it
        interface: enp0s25

lines 1-23...skipping...
enp0s25: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel 82567LM"
        ethernet (e1000e), 00:1F:16:36:23:87, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.134/24
        route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100
        route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
        inet6 fe80::21f:16ff:fe36:2387/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

wls1: unavailable
        "Intel Ultimate N 5300"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 00:21:6A:94:0A:7C, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.1.1
        domains: homenet.telecomitalia.it
        interface: enp0s25

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.
~
~
lines 1-27/27 (END)

blblbl@ubuntu:~$ rfkill listall
Try 'rfkill --help' for more information.
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ sudo sv restart NetworkManager
[sudo] password for blblbl: 
sudo: sv: command not found
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ sudo sv restart NetworkManager
sudo: sv: command not found
blblbl@ubuntu:~$ apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
E: Impossibile aprire il file di blocco /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Impossibile acquisire il blocco sul frontend dpkg (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend). È necessario essere root.

Integrated Wi-Fi Diagnostic Script
---------------------------------

Starting Wi-Fi Diagnostics...
Performing ping test to 8.8.8.8...
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=18.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.448/18.832/19.020/0.226 ms

System Information:
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-130-generic
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU L9400 @ 1.86GHz
Total RAM: 3,7Gi
Last System Update: dic 26 11:46
Wi-Fi Card installed: 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
Wi-Fi Interface Information:
Interface: wls1
Interface wls1
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:21:6a:94:0a:7c
    type managed
    wiphy 0
    txpower 15.00 dBm
Not connected.
Power save: on

VPN (tun0/wg0) detected: Not active
Network Speed Test:
Running speed test, please wait... (Note: The test may appear to hang at 98% for a few minutes. This is normal - wait patiently.)
[================================================= ] 98%
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...                                                                                                                     
Testing from Telecom Italia (95.245.210.112)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by i3D.net (Milan) [478.68 km]: 21.064 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 142.82 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 20.05 Mbit/s


Checking network status with nmcli...
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enp0s25  ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
wls1     wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --                 
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
No active Wi-Fi connection detected or speed not available.
Monitoring Wi-Fi signal and quality with nmcli...
No active Wi-Fi connection found.

Wi-Fi Diagnostic Summary
========================
Wi-Fi Interface:
- wls1
Speed Test Results:
Speed test results not available. The test may have failed or not been performed.
Network Environment
====================
- SSID: 
- Signal Strength:  dBm
- Signal level: N/A%
- Frequency:  MHz
- Power save: on
- VPN Active: No

INSIGHTS
========
System Information:
- Your system specifications are important for Wi-Fi performance. A recent kernel version often includes the latest Wi-Fi drivers and features.
Wi-Fi Interface:
- Connected to network: 
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 401: [: : integer expression expected
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 403: [: : integer expression expected
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 405: [: : integer expression expected
- Unknown frequency band. Characteristics are unknown.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 412: [: : integer expression expected
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 414: [: : integer expression expected
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 416: [: : integer expression expected
- Poor signal strength. Consider moving closer to your router or checking for obstacles.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Wifi-Diagnostic.sh: line 423: [: : integer expression expected
- Lower transmission rate. You might experience slowdowns with high-bandwidth activities.
Speed Test:
- Speed test results not available. Unable to provide insights on network performance.
Network Environment:
- Power save mode is on. This may improve battery life but could potentially impact Wi-Fi performance.

VPN Status:
- No VPN (tun0 OpenVPN or wg0 WireGuard) detected. Your internet traffic is not being routed through a VPN at the moment.

Wi-Fi Diagnostics completed. For a full diagnostic report, check the log file at /home/blblbl/wifi_diagnosis.log

blblbl@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 3 Network
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T400 [17aa:20ee]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:4236]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:1011]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi


Does the wifi switch work?  https://yehar.com/blog/?p=1322

Welcome to ASK. Take a look at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/70971/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products/intel-wireless-series/intel-wifi-link-5300.html which suggests a solution. The second link from that page has been updated very recently.
